# Removing any slide before title page in Beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I'm writing a Beamer presentation, and I'm having one trouble because **before the title page**, it's appearing a slide showing the outline as I show in the picture.

How can I remove this slide? I haven't written any code for it to appear, so how can I fix it in an efficient way.

I post part of the code, so you can tell me if there's something wrong.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\title{Kalman Filter}
\subtitle{A numerical example}
\author{XXXXX}

\begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
\tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
\end{frame}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Slide number 1 (before title page)]

Comment: Just look for `Outline` in your code. I can see it immediately. Just remove the code and the slide in question is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Short answer: Never ignore error messages

You cannot have any slides before `\begin{document}`. In fact this should have caused a huge number of error messages à la `Missing \begin{document}. \end{frame}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\title{Kalman Filter}
\subtitle{A numerical example}
\author{XXXXX}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```